# Accidental downvote, what to do?

Tags: discussion, support

The vote buttons are on the left edge of the screen, right where my fingers fall when scrolling on the iPad, and I have almost accidentally voted one way or another several times....

Now it's no longer "almost", and I **have** voted accidentally.  A downvote.  What should I do? Ask for a minor edit so I can correct it? Post a comment apologizing? Nothing?

Comment: Too late now, but you have a window of a couple minutes where you can undo your vote freely. If there's actually something significant to edit in the post you can go ahead and edit it/undo your vote though.

Comment: There have been threads on other SE where the position was it is acceptable to edit so that you can change your vote... I would not have a problem if it was post and there was a comment explaining that it was done to undo an accidental downvote.

Answer (score 6):

First, let me tell you that you are not alone, I accidentally up/down vote all the time when I'm browsing the site from my mobile. There's a five minute window that you can retract and even reverse your vote, but after that your vote is locked.

*If* the post is a new one (let's say a week old) *and* there's a minor edit you can do that will improve it, I'd say go for it, and then retract your vote. It's a hack, and in general I would advice against minor edits with the sole purpose of changing your vote, every edit however minor bumps the question to the front page, and pushes other questions out of the way.  But a week old post is probably already in the front page, or was there very recently, so go for it (but please don't make a habit of it).

If it's an older post, or the only edit you can think of is something completely pointless, then just forget about it and move on. A single vote (up or down) doesn't say anything for a post, and it will be corrected by the community sooner than later. Try to be a little bit more careful when browsing the site, I don't know how awkward the interface feels on an iPad, but even if you accidentally vote the five minute window gives you enough time to correct your vote.